# Error! How to bypass/change certain syntax for minify process- Javascript

Tags: javascript, minify

**Hi, Unable to minify because some of the codes showing error.**


**The error message --> Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 4, col: 56)**

```
var text = comment.item(i).textContent;
            var phone = '';
            if(text.match(/\d{10,11}/g)!=null){
                phone = text.match(/\d{10,11}/g).map(n => `6${n}`).join(', ');
            }
```

**How to change some of the problem codes before minify process?**


**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, your minifier doesn't support ES6 syntax.
Try to find another minifier or a new version which support ES6 syntax. By 2018, most of them should support ES6.

If it is not possible, you can make it work by getting rid of arrow function and template literal by changing this:

```
phone = text.match(/\d{10,11}/g).map(n => `6${n}`).join(', ');
```

to

```
phone = text.match(/\d{10,11}/g).map(function(n) { return "6" + n; }).join(', ');
```